# Where is radiation density in the Planck 2013 results?

Tags: cosmology, radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

I've been looking at the [Planck 2013 cosmological parameters](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5076) paper, trying to update my toy cosmology simulator with the most recent data.  Most of the interesting values such as $H_0$, $\Omega_m$, and $\Omega_\Lambda$ can be found in Table 2 on page 12, but the one thing I didn't find was an estimate of the energy density of radiation.  Can this be derived from some other parameters in these data?

Comment: It'd be useful if you gave us the link for your simulator. I'd love to enjoy it ;-)

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut I wrote a [blog post](http://reedbeta.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/numerically-modeling-the-expansion-of-the-universe/) about it awhile back, and the code (in Python) is linked from there.  It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The radiation density has two components: the present-day photon density $\rho_\gamma$ and the neutrino density $\rho_\nu$. The photon density as a function of frequency can be derived directly from the CMB: the photon number density follows the Planck law
$$
n(\nu)\,\text{d}\nu = \frac{8\pi\nu^2}{c^3}\frac{\text{d}\nu}{e^{h\nu/k_B T_0}-1},
$$
with $k_B$ the Stefan-Boltzmann constant, and $T_0$ the current CMB temperature. The photon energy density is then
$$
\rho_\gamma\, c^2 = \int_0^{\infty}h\nu\,n(\nu)\,\text{d}\nu = a_B\, T_0^4,
$$
where
$$
a_B = \frac{8\pi^5 k_B^4}{15h^3c^3} = 7.56577\times 10^{-16}\;\text{J}\,\text{m}^{-3}\,\text{K}^{-4}
$$
is the radiation energy constant. With $T_0=2.7255\,\text{K}$, we get
$$
\rho_\gamma = \frac{a_B\, T_0^4}{c^2} = 4.64511\times 10^{-31}\;\text{kg}\,\text{m}^{-3}.
$$
The neutrino density is related to the photon density: in Eq. (1) on page 5 in the paper, you see that
$$
\rho_\nu = 3.046\frac{7}{8}\left(\frac{4}{11}\right)^{4/3}\rho_\gamma.
$$
This relation can be derived from physics in the early universe, when neutrinos and photons were in thermal equilibrium. So
$$
\rho_\nu = 3.21334\times 10^{-31}\;\text{kg}\,\text{m}^{-3},
$$
and the total present-day radiation density is
$$
\rho_{R,0} = \rho_\gamma + \rho_\nu = 7.85846\times 10^{-31}\;\text{kg}\,\text{m}^{-3}.
$$
We can also express this relative to the present-day critical density
$$
\rho_{c,0} = \frac{3H_0^{2}}{8\pi G} = 1.87847\,h^{2}\times 10^{-26}\;\text{kg}\,\text{m}^{-3},
$$
where the Hubble constant is expressed in terms of the dimensionless parameter $h$, as
$$
H_0 = 100\,h\;\text{km}\,\text{s}^{-1}\,\text{Mpc}^{-1},
$$
so we get
$$
\begin{align}
\Omega_{\gamma}\,h^2 &= \dfrac{\rho_\gamma}{\rho_{c,0}}h^2 = 2.47282\times 10^{-5},\\
\Omega_{\nu}\,h^2 &= \dfrac{\rho_\nu}{\rho_{c,0}}h^2 = 1.71061\times 10^{-5},\\
\Omega_{R,0}\,h^2 &= \Omega_{\gamma}\,h^2 + \Omega_{\nu}\,h^2 = 4.18343\times 10^{-5}.
\end{align}
$$
For a Hubble value $h=0.673$, one finds $\Omega_{R,0} = 9.23640\times 10^{-5}$.

I should point out that the formulae for the primordial neutrinos is only valid when they are relativistic, which was true in the early universe. Since neutrinos have a tiny mass, they are probably no longer relativistic in the present-day universe, and behave now like matter instead of radiation. Therefore, neutrinos only contributed to the radiation density in the early universe, while the present-day radiation density only consists of photons.

Comment: Wow! It's truly amazing that a negligible quantity has such a tremendous influence :)

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut It's only negligible today...in the early universe it was the dominant factor, since radiation density scales so strongly (fourth power of the scale factor).

Comment: i think the numerical values for $\Omega_{\gamma}h^2$ and $\Omega_{\nu}h^2$ were switched by mistake.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative approach to Pulsar's great answer is to use the two Planck measurements for the current matter density $\Omega_m$ and the redshift of radiation-matter equality $z_{eq}$. We can use that
$$
\rho_m(z_{eq}) = \rho_R(z_{eq}) \,,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\Omega_{m,0} (z_{eq}+1)^3 = \Omega_{R,0} (z_{eq}+1)^4 \,,
$$
or
$$
\Omega_{R,0} = \Omega_{m,0} / (z_{eq}+1) \,.
$$
Using the values from Table 2 of the 2013 paper (there's a 2015 version by now, as you probably know), from the last column for consistency with Pulsar (right?), we end up with
$$
\Omega_{R,0} = 0.315 / (3391+1) = 9.28656 \times 10^{-5} \,.
$$