# Mass equivalent of CMB

Tags: cosmology

If the 2°K CMB is the portion of big bang energy that didn't get turned into bayonic/dark matter or dark energy (as it now stands) at 380,000 years post bang,  how big is the CMB energy compared to baryonic and dark mass?  (Mass and energy are related by mc**2 or mc^2) .

Comment: Radiation density is around $10^{-4}$ baryon density. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94181/where-is-radiation-density-in-the-planck-2013-results and info about $\Omega_{rad}$ at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model#Parameters The CMB is still the dominant component in the photon population of the universe.