# Radiation Density Parameter Today

Tags: cosmology, radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

I would like to insert in my thesis the value of the radiation density parameter today with its appropriate error and I was checking the latest Planck results [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209). I am a bit confused since I thought I could find directly $\Omega_{rad}$ or deriving it using the value of the radiation Temperature $T_0$. But I couldn't find either of them.

It would be enough the result only for photons since we have to make some assumptions for the neutrino one.

Comment: This could be helpful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94181/where-is-radiation-density-in-the-planck-2013-results

Comment: I can't find $T_0$ in the paper though

Comment: I found the value of the temperature, here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06205.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interested, following [Where is radiation density in the Planck 2013 results?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94181/where-is-radiation-density-in-the-planck-2013-results) and using the result in https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06205 you can find the photon density parameter